# ActiveWeb: testing JSON response attributes and values

Tags: activeweb

What is the preferred way to test JSON response, especially the attributes and values to be present in ? What is the right type of a controller to extend from: `IntegrationSpec`, `ControllerSpec`, `AppIntegrationSpec`? I didn't find the proper response in the corresponding [Testing section](http://javalite.io/testing). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good example if this in this sample project: 
https://github.com/javalite/activeweb-rest/blob/27687e26f5476734b867d01f38b2575c6de3f3c9/src/test/java/app/controllers/PeopleControllerSpec.java#L57

```
public void shouldCreateNewPeopleWithAddresses(){

        String json = Util.readResource("/people.json");
        request().content(json.getBytes()).contentType("application/json").post("create"); // <--- need to call "create" according to REST routing

        Map response = JsonHelper.toMap(responseContent());

        the(response.get("code")).shouldBeEqual(200);
        the(response.get("message")).shouldBeEqual("successfully created people and addresses");
}
```

Basically, you get a `responseContent()` as String, then you can do whatever you want with it. The super class for the spec is irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you for your response. What did you mean under `...the super class for the spec is irrelevant` ?

Comment: Means any super class will do, IntegrationSpec, ControllerSpec, AppIntegrationSpec

Comment: there is also a desire to kill all the spec super-classes leaving just one, that can do it all. Some work has been done in this direction, but not complete. It will be backwards compatible with current super-classes though.